# How To Create "Boating Time" Areas -- ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, maritime-map

I'm fairly new to GIS, and I would like to create what I'm calling a "boat time area". Similar to a drive time area, it would give an area of all the places a boat can be in a given amount of time, with a given starting point. I need to account for terrain that boats would have to navigate around (islands, coasts, etc). How would I achieve this? What tools should I use?

Comment: Do you have access to the Spatial Analyst tools in ArcGIS?

Comment: Are wind or water currents a factor?

Answer (score 2):

One solution to your problem could be a form of cost-distance analysis: http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Cost_Distance_Analysis

http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Cost_Path_Analysis

You can model your area as a raster dataset where islands other land would be extremely high-cost (or impossible) to traverse, then run a least-cost analysis.